# Syntax error when creating a select list by pulling data from Facileforms

Tags: php

Facileforms uses #_records for the record id and #_subrecords for data submitted.  So, I am learning inner joins.  However, I am getting an error.

The error message is..."Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/snbrown/homestest.dreamhosters.com/components/com_breezingforms/facileforms.process.php(1227) : eval()'d code on line 16"

The code is...

```
<?php

$user = JFactory::getUser()->get('id');

JFactory::getDBO()->setQuery "SELECT 
#_facileforms_records.id, 
#_facileforms_subrecords.afname, 
#_facileforms_subrecords.alname,
#_facileforms_subrecords.awebsite, 
#_facileforms_subrecords.aphone, 
#_facileforms_subrecords.aemail, 
#_facileforms_subrecords.abrokerage
FROM #_facileforms_records;
INNER JOIN #_facileforms_subrecords;
ON #_facileforms_records.id=#_facileforms_subrecords.record;
WHERE (#_facileforms_subrecords.name = acustomerid AND value = "$userid");
AND (#_facileforms_subrecords.name = "formid AND value = 4)";

?>
```

Of course, as someone new to joins, it looks as though I am chewing off a bit more than I can handle.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntactical errors that's hard to explain here..

You can try this **`fixed`** code

```
<?php

$user = JFactory::getUser()->get('id');

JFactory::getDBO()->setQuery("SELECT 
#_facileforms_records.id, 
#_facileforms_subrecords.afname, 
#_facileforms_subrecords.alname,
#_facileforms_subrecords.awebsite, 
#_facileforms_subrecords.aphone, 
#_facileforms_subrecords.aemail, 
#_facileforms_subrecords.abrokerage
FROM #_facileforms_records;
INNER JOIN #_facileforms_subrecords;
ON #_facileforms_records.id=#_facileforms_subrecords.record;
WHERE (#_facileforms_subrecords.name = acustomerid AND value = '$userid')
AND (#_facileforms_subrecords.name = 'formid' AND value = 4);");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You corrected block of code are below.

```
JFactory::getDBO()->setQuery("SELECT 
#_facileforms_records.id, 
#_facileforms_subrecords.afname, 
#_facileforms_subrecords.alname,
#_facileforms_subrecords.awebsite, 
#_facileforms_subrecords.aphone, 
#_facileforms_subrecords.aemail, 
#_facileforms_subrecords.abrokerage
FROM #_facileforms_records;
INNER JOIN #_facileforms_subrecords;
ON #_facileforms_records.id=#_facileforms_subrecords.record;
WHERE (#_facileforms_subrecords.name = acustomerid AND value = \"$userid\")
AND (#_facileforms_subrecords.name = \"formid\" AND value = 4);");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, some have post the fixed code but none of them have explain whats the problem, so I will.
The problem here is that you are using double quotes to enclose your query string, but you are also attempt to use double quotes inside your query. If you have the following string

```
$myString = "this is a string with "quotes" inside of it";
```

PHP will think that the string ended in `with"` and that `quotes` is a T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING (an identifier of a constant defined with the define function) so it will throw a syntax error.

You can eliminate the problem using many approaches. In the @Roopendra answer, he escapes the quotes with `\`to make it part of the string, resulting in

In the @Shankar Damodaran he replaced double quotes with single quotes so there is no confusion.